# Where does Subversion log errors?

Tags: svn

I'm having an issue with a Subversion server and can't seem to find Subversion's log files. Specifically, I'm looking for any logfiles that Subversion creates to handle its own internal issues, as opposed to the log messages that a user would create when checking in code. I've tried the official SVN documentation, and I've googled until my fingers bleed, but there's so much documentation on SVN checkin logs that anything on Subversion's internal logging is lost in the shuffle.

The system is [Red Hat Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) 4.1.2 with Subversion version 1.5.1.

Comment: Where does subversion log errors? In clearcase... where you'll never find them again...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are running SVN over [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) (HTTP or HTTPS), you will want to look at Apache's log. By default going to be in `/var/log/httpd`.

The logging including the location is configurable in your `subversion.conf` file. Once you find the logs you're likely going to want to setup a customlog directive to change the format. Something like:

```
LogFormat `"%{%Y-%m-%d %T}t %u@%h %>s repo:%{SVN-REPOS-NAME}e %{SVN-ACTION}e (%B Bytes in %T Sec)"` svn
```

[The red book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.logging) has some good information on it.